# Where to get latest version of libWebRTC.a for iOS which supports IPv6?

Tags: ios, webrtc, ipv6

I am maintaining an iOS app, which is built with WebRTC. The original developer has included a prebuilt "libWebRTC.a" in the project. However, since June 2016, Apple has made it mandatory for all iOS apps to support IPv6.

The current implementation that I have doesn't work with IPv6. While searching more on the topic I came across this issue:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=5871

Which seems to indicate that WebRTC library had issues with IPv6 only networks which were fixed in June 2016.

Unfortunately I am not able to find the most recent version libWebRTC. I came across multiple projects on GitHub which seems to point to this project:

https://github.com/pristineio/webrtc-build-scripts

But it seems that this project may not work because Google switched to GN from GYP as one of the build tools.

It will be great to know if any of you have managed to solve this and get WebRTC calls to work on iOS on IPv6 only networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add cocoa pod which have latest webrtc lib here:

https://cocoapods.org/?q=Webrtc

Comment: https://github.com/Anakros/WebRTC-iOS - this one is the latest as of now. Since it comes has the given Cocoa Pod link accepting the answer. I have confirmed that the AppRTCDemo built with this version of WebRTC works on IPv6 only network.

Comment: Hi Pritam, it is failing for me, any suggestions?